# SSH without invoking shell

Tags: ssh, shell, protocol

I've managed to mess up some shared libraries on my system, and now my shell cannot be run, thus locking me out of the system. Both `ssh`, `sftp`, and `scp`, as configured on the remote system, seem to rely on the shell, so those alternatives are out. Really, it is not a big issue because I have some remote hands that can change my shell to `sh` via console.

However I'm curious, getting down to the mechanics of the SSH protocol, whether it is possible to authenticate and perform some manipulations on the remote system (eg, modifying `/etc/passwd`), without ever invoking the shell?

**EDIT**

Just to be fair, to the fellow who suggested specifying the alternative command/shell *after* the ssh command string (eg, `ssh myhost /bin/sh`): the man page *does* state:

```
If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.
```

which could definitely be confusing.

Comment: Change your login shell. If you normally use `bash` see whether you can edit `passwd` and use `sh` or `tsh` (or whatever) based on what you have installed.

Comment: @ericx, unfortunately that would require network access to the remote system, which I do not have due to the issue. Though, in fact someone on the remote end can change the shell via console

Comment: @ericx - Never recommend that people edit /etc/passwd directly. Instead, we should always use `vipw` or for this instance, `chsh`.

Comment: @chsh Please.. You can't, in fact, do it successfully. It's merely a metaphor for everyone in the room. Someone might be using LDAP, or someone might be using Kerberos or any of a myriad of other PAM options. The comment char length is somewhat limited.

Comment: @EEAA I didn't know about vipw. Never came up, but it's a good thing to have in my back pocket. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 4):

[for the record only -- at the time of writing, the problem has long been fixed, hopefully]

With `openssh`, ANY command executed by `sshd` is executed via your login shell with the `-c` option:

- command passed in the `ssh` command line (i.e. `ssh user@host command`)
- command set up in the `.authorized_keys` file (i.e. `command="..." ssh-rsa AAAA...`)
- command specified by the `ForceCommand` option in `sshd_config`
- the execution of the `~/.ssh/rc` script (via `/bin/sh ~/.ssh/rc`)
- even the `scp` commands local to a server executed in response to a remote `scp`

So, if your login shell is faked (`/bin/false` or `nologin`) or broken, there is no way for you to execute anything remotely with `ssh`. That's also why no alternative shell is possible.

Comment: `sftp` doesn't seem to work either in such a situation. If my first line of .bashrc is `echo SOMETHING`, then when trying `sftp localhost`, I get `Received message too long 168435779` as an error, and sftp exits.

Comment: You are right. I don't remember what I had in mind when I wrote that sftp might be useful, since it contradicts what I wrote just above. I guess I meant some sftp-only account (`ForceCommand internal-sftp` in the account configuration). Removing that sentence since it's confusing.